# If we have L3/L2+ switches with encryptors , then why there is a need of firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, switching

Suppose you have two locations City1,City2.

We have L3/L2+ switches with encryptors in both locations. Further we need to have a firewall in between the network.

what is the advantage of putting firewall in network while packets are travelling in encrypted format .

Comment: This question should be on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Firewall is used to secure your network from virus , unwanted/ unauthenticated access, limit the access time and day and so on . Encryptors role only to encrypt packets and it can't restrict the unauthorized access, viruses & attacks to your network.

Comment: The access rules can be set on L3/L2+ managed devices also. So, why to have a firewall on network.

Comment: but L2+/ L3/ managed switches have limitation(approx 15  to 10k) to create rules while firewalls have no such limitations.